# Vigenere cypher, incorrect code

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

I'm doing a vigenere cypher (and have looked at I believe every question asked on the subject on this forum), which is supposed to take a command line input, validate it, and then cypher a requested string of plaintext with that command line input (which is supposed to be only letters).

I have the following code, which I THINK is close, but it keeps spitting out an incorrect cypher.

I'm relatively confident the it has to do with how I am looping through the cypher key, but I cannot figure it out even after hours of effort, searching, etc. I know this problem has been discussed quite a bit but I am trying to understand the logic of why my code is wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[]){
    if (argc != 2){
    printf("error1\n");
    return 1;
    }

   string s1 = argv[1];

   for (int i=0; i < strlen(s1); i++){
   if (((isalpha(s1[i])) == false)){
   printf("error2\n");
   return 2;
        }}

string s = get_string();
int x = strlen(s);

string key = argv[1];
int y = strlen(key);

for (int i=0; i < y; i++){

if (islower(s[i])){
   int lower = ((s[i] -97) + ((key[x%y] -97) % 26) + 97);
   printf("%c",lower);
                    }

else if (isupper(s[i])){
   int upper = (((s[i] -65) + ((key[x%y]) + 65)  % 26) + 65);
   printf("%c",upper);
                    }
else {
    printf("%c",s[i]);
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger, your code has more than one problems. For example key[x%y] will be the same at each iteration because x and y are not changing, and why use different offset values for key depending on s[i] being upper or lower?

Comment: "but it keeps spitting out an incorrect cypher" What do you expect? What do you got?